# set object value to vue data property

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I'm new to vuejs. I'm trying to do set an object value to vue data property but it is not seems working

```js
  data: () => ({
    newTodo: "",
    todoObj: { title: newTodo, undo: false },
    toDoList: [
      { title: "Study", undo: false },
      { title: "Work", undo: false },
      { title: "Gaming", undo: false },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    addNewToList() {
      this.toDoList.push(this.todoObj);
      this.newTodo = "";
    },
  },
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.4/vue.js"></script>
```

the idea is I bind newTodo to input and then push object to array. But is newTodo is undefined. also let me know if there's any better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you remove `todoObj` and in your method just do this

```
this.todoList.push({value: this.newTodo, undo: false})
```

It minimizes you from declaring variable.

The error come from this code `{ title: newTodo, undo: false }`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template for this kind of task.

```
<script>
  const newTodoTemplate = {
    title: '',
    undo: false,
  }
  export default {
    name: 'Index',
    data: () => ({
      todoObj: { ...newTodoTemplate },
      toDoList: [
        { title: "Study", undo: false },
        { title: "Work", undo: false },
        { title: "Gaming", undo: false },
      ],
    }),
    methods: {
      addNewToList() {
       this.toDoList.push(this.todoObj);
       this.todoObj = { ...newTodoTemplate }
      },
  },
}
</script>
```

By creating the template you are always copying the template object to the `todoObj` object and when ever you are adding to the list you are pushing the `todoObj` which is eventually carrying the template.

This way you can take input of a newTodo in `todoObj.title` and after pushing ; as you are copying the template the previous one will be cleared